# Can I set my own map on facebook event created by Graph API?

Tags: android, ios, facebook-graph-api, google-maps-api-3, windows-mobile

I want to create an event through Graph API in a mobile app. It doesn't matter the platform (iOS, Android, WP7). I would like to embed my custom map from Google maps in the event, instead the default Bing map that facebook creates.
Is it possible?
I don't see the way in the API documentation page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Only map provided by Facebook (Bing) will be displayed for the event.

Facebook isn't providing way to customize this, not with API and not with regular Facebook site.